# Unable to access tomcat deployed java web application using godaddy domain name

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, dns

We have VPS  and domain name by go daddy .  We have deployed java web application in tomcat installed on VPS. I  am able to acccess appplication by ip address

for example : xxxx.xxxx:xxx:xxxx:8080/mysampleweb     but  i want  to acccess the same application by my registered domain name i.e www.mysampleweb.com

what i did 
1) I have added host entry in tomcat server.xml 
2) map domain name with IP in DNS in godaddy account 
3) Changed port from 8080 to 80 but no luck

Can any one share me details step to map/access  tomcat deployed web application  on VPS by registered domain name

Comment: I'm not familiar with tomcat, but did you restart the service after changing the port specification?

Comment: Yes i did restart tomcat

Comment: Am getting this error : The requested URL /mysampleweb  was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.                                                                                     Server.xml changes         <Host name="mysampleweb.com"   appBase="webapps"
        <Context path="" docBase="/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/webapps/mysampleweb"/>
</Host>

Comment: You're changing a lot at once. Is your tomcat still up with ip address?

Comment: Did you change the DNS settings? They might take a few hours to propagate, depending on the previous DNS settings (there's a timeout, can be up to a week). Try `ping <your-ip-address>` and `ping <your-domain-name>`. They should both display that they're pinging the same IP address. If they do: Try accessing tomcat again - the DNS propagation might have happened in the mean time. Otherwise: report back.

Answer (score 1):

Open the server.xml file

```
  <Alias>www.test.local</Alias>

  <Context path="" docBase="ExtractedWARName" debug="0" privileged="true" />

  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
         directory="logs"   prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
         pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false" />
```

where ExtractedWARName is the war extracted folder name.